# Ionic commands not recognized and Npm install creating unnecessary files

Tags: node.js, ionic-framework, npm, npm-install

I have recently moved computers in my work and I have cloned my code from github in order to work with it on my new computer. When i opened my ionic project I tried to use ionic serve to ensure everything was running okay and I was getting an error message of:

> The term 'ionic' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.

I then tried some solutions from stack such as npm install ionic -g and this creates a lot of files that I have never seen before like these:

[image]

An example of code inside one of them is:

```
#!/bin/sh
basedir=$(dirname "$(echo "$0" | sed -e 's,\\,/,g')")

case `uname` in
*CYGWIN*) basedir=`cygpath -w "$basedir"`;;
esac

if [ -x "$basedir/node" ]; then
 "$basedir/node"  "$basedir/node_modules/mocha/bin/_mocha" "$@"
 ret=$?
else 
 node  "$basedir/node_modules/mocha/bin/_mocha" "$@"
 ret=$?
 fi
exit $ret
```

I'm not sure why these are being created each time? Does anyone know what I need to do?

Terminal Code:

> PS C:\Users\aarogers\Documents\GitHub\almac-clinical-services-app>
>   PS C:\Users\aarogers\Documents\GitHub\almac-clinical-services-app> npm install
>   C:\Users\aarogers\Documents\GitHub\almac-clinical-services-app\parser -> C:\Users\aarogers\Documents\GitHub\almac-clinical-services-app\node_modules@babel\parser\bin\babel-parser.js
>   C:\Users\aarogers\Documents\GitHub\almac-clinical-services-app\acorn -> C:\Users\aarogers\Documents\GitHub\almac-clinical-services-app\node_modules\acorn\bin\acorn
>   C:\Users\aarogers\Documents\GitHub\almac-clinical-services-app\ansi-html -> C:\Users\aarogers\Documents\GitHub\almac-clinical-services-app\node_modules\ansi-html\bin\ansi-html
>   C:\Users\aarogers\Documents\GitHub\almac-clinical-services-app\atob -> C:\Users\aarogers\Documents\GitHub\almac-clinical-services-app\node_modules\atob\bin\atob.js
>   C:\Users\aarogers\Documents\GitHub\almac-clinical-services-app\babylon -> C:\Users\aarogers\Documents\GitHub\almac-clinical-services-app\node_modules\babylon\bin\babylon.js
>   C:\Users\aarogers\Documents\GitHub\almac-clinical-services-app\cssesc -> C:\Users\aarogers\Documents\GitHub\almac-clinical-services-app\node_modules\cssesc\bin\cssesc
>   C:\Users\aarogers\Documents\GitHub\almac-clinical-services-app\esparse -> C:\Users\aarogers\Documents\GitHub\almac-clinical-services-app\node_modules\esprima\bin\esparse.js
>   C:\Users\aarogers\Documents\GitHub\almac-clinical-services-app\esvalidate -> C:\Users\aarogers\Documents\GitHub\almac-clinical-services-app\node_modules\esprima\bin\esvalidate.js
>   C:\Users\aarogers\Documents\GitHub\almac-clinical-services-app\he -> C:\Users\aarogers\Documents\GitHub\almac-clinical-services-app\node_modules\he\bin\he
>   C:\Users\aarogers\Documents\GitHub\almac-clinical-services-app\image-size -> C:\Users\aarogers\Documents\GitHub\almac-clinical-services-app\node_modules\image-size\bin\image-size.js
>   C:\Users\aarogers\Documents\GitHub\almac-clinical-services-app\not-in-install -> C:\Users\aarogers\Documents\GitHub\almac-clinical-services-app\node_modules\in-publish\not-in-install.js
>   C:\Users\aarogers\Documents\GitHub\almac-clinical-services-app\in-install -> C:\Users\aarogers\Documents\GitHub\almac-clinical-services-app\node_modules\in-publish\in-install.js
>   C:\Users\aarogers\Documents\GitHub\almac-clinical-services-app\not-in-publish -> C:\Users\aarogers\Documents\GitHub\almac-clinical-services-app\node_modules\in-publish\not-in-publish.js
>   C:\Users\aarogers\Documents\GitHub\almac-clinical-services-app\in-publish -> C:\Users\aarogers\Documents\GitHub\almac-clinical-services-app\node_modules\in-publish\in-publish.js
>   C:\Users\aarogers\Documents\GitHub\almac-clinical-services-app\is-ci -> C:\Users\aarogers\Documents\GitHub\almac-clinical-services-app\node_modules\is-ci\bin.js
>   C:\Users\aarogers\Documents\GitHub\almac-clinical-services-app\jsesc -> C:\Users\aarogers\Documents\GitHub\almac-clinical-services-app\node_modules\jsesc\bin\jsesc
>   C:\Users\aarogers\Documents\GitHub\almac-clinical-services-app\loose-envify -> C:\Users\aarogers\Documents\GitHub\almac-clinical-services-app\node_modules\loose-envify\cli.js
>   C:\Users\aarogers\Documents\GitHub\almac-clinical-services-app\miller-rabin -> C:\Users\aarogers\Documents\GitHub\almac-clinical-services-app\node_modules\miller-rabin\bin\miller-rabin
>   C:\Users\aarogers\Documents\GitHub\almac-clinical-services-app\mime -> C:\Users\aarogers\Documents\GitHub\almac-clinical-services-app\node_modules\mime\cli.js
>   C:\Users\aarogers\Documents\GitHub\almac-clinical-services-app\watch -> C:\Users\aarogers\Documents\GitHub\almac-clinical-services-app\node_modules@cnakazawa\watch\cli.js
>   C:\Users\aarogers\Documents\GitHub\almac-clinical-services-app\blocking-proxy -> C:\Users\aarogers\Documents\GitHub\almac-clinical-services-app\node_modules\blocking-proxy\built\lib\bin.js
>   C:\Users\aarogers\Documents\GitHub\almac-clinical-services-app\json5 -> C:\Users\aarogers\Documents\GitHub\almac-clinical-services-app\node_modules\json5\lib\cli.js
>   C:\Users\aarogers\Documents\GitHub\almac-clinical-services-app\mkdirp -> C:\Users\aarogers\Documents\GitHub\almac-clinical-services-app\node_modules\mkdirp\bin\cmd.js
>   C:\Users\aarogers\Documents\GitHub\almac-clinical-services-app\nopt -> C:\Users\aarogers\Documents\GitHub\almac-clinical-services-app\node_modules\nopt\bin\nopt.js
>   C:\Users\aarogers\Documents\GitHub\almac-clinical-services-app\errno -> C:\Users\aarogers\Documents\GitHub\almac-clinical-services-app\node_modules\errno\cli.js
>   C:\Users\aarogers\Documents\GitHub\almac-clinical-services-app\regjsparser -> C:\Users\aarogers\Documents\GitHub\almac-clinical-services-app\node_modules\regjsparser\bin\parser
>   C:\Users\aarogers\Documents\GitHub\almac-clinical-services-app\import-local-fixture -> C:\Users\aarogers\Documents\GitHub\almac-clinical-services-app\node_modules\import-local\fixtures\cli.js
>   C:\Users\aarogers\Documents\GitHub\almac-clinical-services-app\semver -> C:\Users\aarogers\Documents\GitHub\almac-clinical-services-app\node_modules\semver\bin\semver
>   C:\Users\aarogers\Documents\GitHub\almac-clinical-services-app\browserslist -> C:\Users\aarogers\Documents\GitHub\almac-clinical-services-app\node_modules\browserslist\cli.js
>   C:\Users\aarogers\Documents\GitHub\almac-clinical-services-app\sha.js -> C:\Users\aarogers\Documents\GitHub\almac-clinical-services-app\node_modules\sha.js\bin.js
>   C:\Users\aarogers\Documents\GitHub\almac-clinical-services-app\js-yaml -> C:\Users\aarogers\Documents\GitHub\almac-clinical-services-app\node_modules\js-yaml\bin\js-yaml.js
>   C:\Users\aarogers\Documents\GitHub\almac-clinical-services-app\strip-indent -> C:\Users\aarogers\Documents\GitHub\almac-clinical-services-app\node_modules\strip-indent\cli.js
>   C:\Users\aarogers\Documents\GitHub\almac-clinical-services-app\autoprefixer -> C:\Users\aarogers\Documents\GitHub\almac-clinical-services-app\node_modules\autoprefixer\bin\autoprefixer
>   C:\Users\aarogers\Documents\GitHub\almac-clinical-services-app\terser -> C:\Users\aarogers\Documents\GitHub\almac-clinical-services-app\node_modules\terser\bin\uglifyjs
>   C:\Users\aarogers\Documents\GitHub\almac-clinical-services-app\JSONStream -> C:\Users\aarogers\Documents\GitHub\almac-clinical-services-app\node_modules\JSONStream\bin.js
>   C:\Users\aarogers\Documents\GitHub\almac-clinical-services-app\multicast-dns -> C:\Users\aarogers\Documents\GitHub\almac-clinical-services-app\node_modules\multicast-dns\cli.js
>   C:\Users\aarogers\Documents\GitHub\almac-clinical-services-app\tree-kill -> C:\Users\aarogers\Documents\GitHub\almac-clinical-services-app\node_modules\tree-kill\cli.js
>   C:\Users\aarogers\Documents\GitHub\almac-clinical-services-app\ts-jest -> C:\Users\aarogers\Documents\GitHub\almac-clinical-services-app\node_modules\ts-jest\cli.js
>   C:\Users\aarogers\Documents\GitHub\almac-clinical-services-app\sshpk-conv -> C:\Users\aarogers\Documents\GitHub\almac-clinical-services-app\node_modules\sshpk\bin\sshpk-conv
>   C:\Users\aarogers\Documents\GitHub\almac-clinical-services-app\sshpk-sign -> C:\Users\aarogers\Documents\GitHub\almac-clinical-services-app\node_modules\sshpk\bin\sshpk-sign
>   C:\Users\aarogers\Documents\GitHub\almac-clinical-services-app\sshpk-verify -> C:\Users\aarogers\Documents\GitHub\almac-clinical-services-app\node_modules\sshpk\bin\sshpk-verify
>   C:\Users\aarogers\Documents\GitHub\almac-clinical-services-app\escodegen -> C:\Users\aarogers\Documents\GitHub\almac-clinical-services-app\node_modules\escodegen\bin\escodegen.js
>   C:\Users\aarogers\Documents\GitHub\almac-clinical-services-app\esgenerate -> C:\Users\aarogers\Documents\GitHub\almac-clinical-services-app\node_modules\escodegen\bin\esgenerate.js
>   C:\Users\aarogers\Documents\GitHub\almac-clinical-services-app\uglifyjs -> C:\Users\aarogers\Documents\GitHub\almac-clinical-services-app\node_modules\uglify-js\bin\uglifyjs
>   C:\Users\aarogers\Documents\GitHub\almac-clinical-services-app\uuid -> C:\Users\aarogers\Documents\GitHub\almac-clinical-services-app\node_modules\uuid\bin\uuid
>   C:\Users\aarogers\Documents\GitHub\almac-clinical-services-app\lessc -> C:\Users\aarogers\Documents\GitHub\almac-clinical-services-app\node_modules\less\bin\lessc
>   C:\Users\aarogers\Documents\GitHub\almac-clinical-services-app\build-optimizer -> C:\Users\aarogers\Documents\GitHub\almac-clinical-services-app\node_modules@angular-devkit\build-optimizer\src\build-optimizer\cli.js
>   C:\Users\aarogers\Documents\GitHub\almac-clinical-services-app\which -> C:\Users\aarogers\Documents\GitHub\almac-clinical-services-app\node_modules\which\bin\which
>   C:\Users\aarogers\Documents\GitHub\almac-clinical-services-app\handlebars -> C:\Users\aarogers\Documents\GitHub\almac-clinical-services-app\node_modules\handlebars\bin\handlebars
>   C:\Users\aarogers\Documents\GitHub\almac-clinical-services-app\jasmine -> C:\Users\aarogers\Documents\GitHub\almac-clinical-services-app\node_modules\jasmine\bin\jasmine.js
>   C:\Users\aarogers\Documents\GitHub\almac-clinical-services-app\rimraf -> C:\Users\aarogers\Documents\GitHub\almac-clinical-services-app\node_modules\rimraf\bin.js
>   C:\Users\aarogers\Documents\GitHub\almac-clinical-services-app\node-gyp -> C:\Users\aarogers\Documents\GitHub\almac-clinical-services-app\node_modules\node-gyp\bin\node-gyp.js
>   C:\Users\aarogers\Documents\GitHub\almac-clinical-services-app\shjs -> C:\Users\aarogers\Documents\GitHub\almac-clinical-services-app\node_modules\shelljs\bin\shjs
>   C:\Users\aarogers\Documents\GitHub\almac-clinical-services-app\tape -> C:\Users\aarogers\Documents\GitHub\almac-clinical-services-app\node_modules\tape\bin\tape
>   C:\Users\aarogers\Documents\GitHub\almac-clinical-services-app\mocha -> C:\Users\aarogers\Documents\GitHub\almac-clinical-services-app\node_modules\mocha\bin\mocha
>   C:\Users\aarogers\Documents\GitHub\almac-clinical-services-app_mocha -> C:\Users\aarogers\Documents\GitHub\almac-clinical-services-app\node_modules\mocha\bin_mocha
>   C:\Users\aarogers\Documents\GitHub\almac-clinical-services-app\sane -> C:\Users\aarogers\Documents\GitHub\almac-clinical-services-app\node_modules\sane\src\cli.js
>   C:\Users\aarogers\Documents\GitHub\almac-clinical-services-app\stylus -> C:\Users\aarogers\Documents\GitHub\almac-clinical-services-app\node_modules\stylus\bin\stylus
>   C:\Users\aarogers\Documents\GitHub\almac-clinical-services-app\ios-sim -> C:\Users\aarogers\Documents\GitHub\almac-clinical-services-app\node_modules\ios-sim\bin\ios-sim
>   C:\Users\aarogers\Documents\GitHub\almac-clinical-services-app\jest-runtime -> C:\Users\aarogers\Documents\GitHub\almac-clinical-services-app\node_modules\jest-runtime\bin\jest-runtime.js
>   C:\Users\aarogers\Documents\GitHub\almac-clinical-services-app\webpack -> C:\Users\aarogers\Documents\GitHub\almac-clinical-services-app\node_modules\webpack\bin\webpack.js
>   C:\Users\aarogers\Documents\GitHub\almac-clinical-services-app\webpack-dev-server -> C:\Users\aarogers\Documents\GitHub\almac-clinical-services-app\node_modules\webpack-dev-server\bin\webpack-dev-server.js
>   C:\Users\aarogers\Documents\GitHub\almac-clinical-services-app\sassgraph -> C:\Users\aarogers\Documents\GitHub\almac-clinical-services-app\node_modules\sass-graph\bin\sassgraph
>   C:\Users\aarogers\Documents\GitHub\almac-clinical-services-app\node-sass -> C:\Users\aarogers\Documents\GitHub\almac-clinical-services-app\node_modules\node-sass\bin\node-sass
>   C:\Users\aarogers\Documents\GitHub\almac-clinical-services-app\ng -> C:\Users\aarogers\Documents\GitHub\almac-clinical-services-app\node_modules@angular\cli\bin\ng
>   C:\Users\aarogers\Documents\GitHub\almac-clinical-services-app\ng-xi18n -> C:\Users\aarogers\Documents\GitHub\almac-clinical-services-app\node_modules@angular\compiler-cli\src\extract_i18n.js
>   C:\Users\aarogers\Documents\GitHub\almac-clinical-services-app\ivy-ngcc -> C:\Users\aarogers\Documents\GitHub\almac-clinical-services-app\node_modules@angular\compiler-cli\src\ngcc\main-ngcc.js
>   C:\Users\aarogers\Documents\GitHub\almac-clinical-services-app\ngc -> C:\Users\aarogers\Documents\GitHub\almac-clinical-services-app\node_modules@angular\compiler-cli\src\main.js
>   C:\Users\aarogers\Documents\GitHub\almac-clinical-services-app\capacitor -> C:\Users\aarogers\Documents\GitHub\almac-clinical-services-app\node_modules@capacitor\cli\bin\capacitor
>   C:\Users\aarogers\Documents\GitHub\almac-clinical-services-app\cap -> C:\Users\aarogers\Documents\GitHub\almac-clinical-services-app\node_modules@capacitor\cli\bin\capacitor
>   C:\Users\aarogers\Documents\GitHub\almac-clinical-services-app\ionic-lab -> C:\Users\aarogers\Documents\GitHub\almac-clinical-services-app\node_modules@ionic\lab\bin\ionic-lab
>   C:\Users\aarogers\Documents\GitHub\almac-clinical-services-app\create -> C:\Users\aarogers\Documents\GitHub\almac-clinical-services-app\node_modules\cordova-android\bin\create
>   C:\Users\aarogers\Documents\GitHub\almac-clinical-services-app\jest -> C:\Users\aarogers\Documents\GitHub\almac-clinical-services-app\node_modules\jest\bin\jest.js
>   C:\Users\aarogers\Documents\GitHub\almac-clinical-services-app\karma -> C:\Users\aarogers\Documents\GitHub\almac-clinical-services-app\node_modules\karma\bin\karma
>   C:\Users\aarogers\Documents\GitHub\almac-clinical-services-app\webdriver-manager -> C:\Users\aarogers\Documents\GitHub\almac-clinical-services-app\node_modules\protractor\bin\webdriver-manager
>   C:\Users\aarogers\Documents\GitHub\almac-clinical-services-app\protractor -> C:\Users\aarogers\Documents\GitHub\almac-clinical-services-app\node_modules\protractor\bin\protractor
>   C:\Users\aarogers\Documents\GitHub\almac-clinical-services-app\ts-node -> C:\Users\aarogers\Documents\GitHub\almac-clinical-services-app\node_modules\ts-node\dist\bin.js
>   C:\Users\aarogers\Documents\GitHub\almac-clinical-services-app\tslint -> C:\Users\aarogers\Documents\GitHub\almac-clinical-services-app\node_modules\tslint\bin\tslint
>   C:\Users\aarogers\Documents\GitHub\almac-clinical-services-app\tsc -> C:\Users\aarogers\Documents\GitHub\almac-clinical-services-app\node_modules\typescript\bin\tsc
>   C:\Users\aarogers\Documents\GitHub\almac-clinical-services-app\tsserver -> C:\Users\aarogers\Documents\GitHub\almac-clinical-services-app\node_modules\typescript\bin\tsserver
>
> node-sass@4.12.0 install C:\Users\aarogers\Documents\GitHub\almac-clinical-services-app\node_modules\node-sass
>   node scripts/install.js

```
ANSI.HTML
> node_modules
.gitignore
.idea
.travis.yml
test
examples
```

Would greatly appreciate the help!

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure why the .cmd files are created
Try the following steps:
1. Delete the current project and clone it again from Github. Run `npm cache clear --force`
2. Check if the Ionic CLI is installed on your PC with `ionic -v`, if the command doesn't return a version, install Ionic with `npm install -g ionic` (Windows)
3. Move to the project folder `cd ./path` (or) open the project in an editor (VS Code)
4. Run `npm install` to install package dependencies.
5. run `ionic serve` (optional)

Edit: 
Remove the node_modules with the following commands
Install rimraf globally `npm install rimraf`
Run rimraf node_modules
Delete the files if they are still present
Run `npm clear cache --force`
According to this description from the [official website](https://docs.npmjs.com/files/folders.html):

> When in global mode, executables are linked into {prefix}/bin on Unix,
>   or directly into {prefix} on Windows.
>
> When in local mode, executables are linked into ./node_modules/.bin so
>   that they can be made available to scripts run through npm. (For
>   example, so that a test runner will be in the path when you run npm
>   test.)

Try running the commands locally on the computer.
If the files are still generated then from [this discussion](https://www.bountysource.com/issues/56706138-git-bash-is-trying-to-look-for-node_modules-in-its-own-folder-module-js-549-throw-err), I conclude that this is a problem caused by antivirus, so try uninstalling the antivirus (or) report this bug to the antivirus organisation.

Comment: Hi Raj! I deleted the current folder, cloned again and ran the cache clear. The Ionic version i got back was 5.4.4. I opened the new folder in VS Code and ran npm install but it is still making the files.  I am going to edit my post to show u the terminal:

Comment: It seems to be when this is run it is creating the files does this make anything clearer?

Comment: Could you show me the .npmignore file in any of the node_module say ansi-html

Comment: Do you have an active antivirus software running on your PC?

Comment: i should do yes - im in a company.

Comment: That seems to be the problem according to a discussion [here](https://www.bountysource.com/issues/56706138-git-bash-is-trying-to-look-for-node_modules-in-its-own-folder-module-js-549-throw-err). I will try to post a solution as soon as I'm off work.

Comment: Thanks Raj really appreciate the help! Im quite a beginner so its a big help

Comment: A clarification, when are those files created after running npm install or ionic serve? and is the antivirus Comodo?

Comment: its during npm install - near the end of it finishing. and the antivirus is Sophos Endpoint?

Comment: i am trying to run "rimraf node_modules" but getting this error "the term rimraf is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function or script file"?

Comment: install rimraf with the following command : npm install -g rimraf, which O.S are you working on?

Comment: windows mate! and okay ill try that - also can i run these commands from inside visual studio terminal inside project folder or where do i run them?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/201088/discussion-between-raj-datta-manohar-and-thealmac2).

Comment: Hi Raj - i was off for a few days. I am going to try when i get home but still receiving errors and the files being generated